# Comparing id s of same column and assign value of one to another

Tags: sql-server

I have table with

```
id name 
1  aa
1  bb
2  ff
3  df
```

I want to check if value is repeated in column "id" then assign the "name" value to next matching ids row 
Expected:

```
id name
1   aa
1   aa
2   ff
3   df
```

Can any one suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: @user187664 - are you saying you want `name` value on each row to be the `min(name)` value for each id?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, 
                    MIN(name) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                    ORDER BY name ASC) rn 
             FROM test)
UPDATE cte 
SET name=rn
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b341761afaa15d816b109393f940bb82)

This will work on the basis of the "lower" letters (IE 'A') will overwrite "higher" letters (IE 'B'), as you have not indicated any preference for how to handle this ordering.